# How to get CSS table-cell to 100% for responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design, multiple-columns, css-tables

How do I get the following setup with CSS to work?

[image: layout]

## jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/16ex38mL/2/

Basically, I intend to put an input box to #header-nav-content-search and let the div and the one below it resize responsively to 100% of the remaining width.
I have two static width columns. One is the first one with 240px, and one is the last one with 200px.

## code

```
#header-nav-content-search {
  width: 100%;
}
```

didn't do the trick.

Comment: best drawing ever :P

Comment: powered by microsoft journal :D ... borders should be even though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have concentrated on reducing the HTML markup needed. The following example is mainly based on that excellent sketch of yours, so it will need some tweaking.

## Basic Idea

Create a three "column" CSS table with the center cell remaining fluid:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell center">I contain 4 fluid divs with the class ".inner"</div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

The center cell contains your 4 inner boxes with the class `.inner`

## Basic CSS Styles

- `box-sizing: border-box` will allow us to calculate percentage width including padding and borders
- The main container, `.table`, is given a fixed height (could be changed to percentage)
- The `.inner` divs are `display: inline-block` and are given appropriate percentage widths and fixed heights equal to half the containers height
- The left and right columns are given their fixed widths
- `.table` is given an appropriate min-width to prevent the inner divs from overlapping

**Note:** In the HTML markup, the inner divs closing and opening tags have no space between them. This is important as it prevents a gap that is present with inline elements.

Refer to [this article for more information.](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

CSS / HTML / Demo

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 600px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.left {
  width: 240px;
}
.right {
  width: 200px;
  border-left: solid 1px #000;
}
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.center-left {
  width: 30%;
}
.center-right {
  width: 70%;
}
/* Borders */

.table {
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
.inner {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
  border-left: solid 1px #000;
}
.center-right .inner {
  border-right: solid 1px #000;
}
.inner:nth-child(3),
.inner:nth-child(4) {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell left">
    240px width
  </div>
  
  <div class="cell center">
    <div class="inner center-left">
      30% width 50% height
    </div><div class="inner center-right">
      70% width 50% height
    </div><div class="inner center-left">
      30% width 50% height
    </div><div class="inner center-right">
      70% width 50% height
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cell right">
    200px width
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfect answer. how could I make the inner-lefts not fluid, but as wide as their content is?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do it that way. Here's one way to get you started.[image]

## DEMO: http://jsbin.com/faveca/1/

*http://jsbin.com/faveca/1/edit*

HTML:

```
 <header>
    
  <div class="fixed-width-240 eq">
    240px column fixed width what about is it equal to the others, yes it is.
   </div>
        
   <div class="fluid eq">
     fluid column
   </div>
    
    <div class="fixed-width-200 eq">
      200px column
    </div>

  </header>
```

CSS

```
body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header div,
header div:before,
header div:after {
    box-sizing: border-box
}
header {
    border: 2px solid #000
}
header:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.fixed-width-240 {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
}
.fixed-width-200 {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    background: orange;
}
.fluid {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #ccc;
}
@media (min-width:700px) { 
    header {
        overflow: hidden
    }
    header .eq {
        padding-bottom: 99999px;
        margin-bottom: -99999px;
    }
    .fixed-width-240,
    .fixed-width-200 {
        float: left
    }
    .fixed-width-240 {
        width: 240px;
        width: 240px;
        margin-right: -240px;
        border-right: 2px solid #000;
    }
    .fixed-width-200 {
        float: right;
        z-index: 2;
        width: 200px;
        margin-left: -200px;
        border-left: 2px solid #000;
    }
    .fluid {
        float: left;
        padding: 0 220px 0 260px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```